# FactCurrentWorkItem and DimWorkItem tables in Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm trying to understand the relationship of the FactCurrentWorkItem and DimWorkItem tables in the Tfs_Warehouse database.

About mid page at the link below it states:

*You can query for information about tasks, bugs, and other types of work items by using the work item tables in the following illustration. Each work item fact table uses the work item dimension table to store many details about the work items.*

I am surprised that there are many FactCurrentWorkItem to one DimWorkItem.  I would have expected the reverse so I have a misunderstanding of what is actually in the tables.  Can someone explain to me what is in them and their relationship?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/table-reference-relational-warehouse-database

Comment: Do you understand how data warehouses work? If not, start by understanding what Facts and Dimensions are, and that will probably eliminate your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below contents will be helpful for you to understand the relationships:

> ### The relational database or data warehouse
>
> Each tool describes its contribution to the data warehouse in an XML
>   schema. The schema specifies the fields that are written to the
>   relational database as dimensions, measures, and details. The schema
>   is also mapped directly into the cube.
>
> The data in the warehouse are stored in a set of tables organized in a
>   star schema. The central table of the star schema is called the fact
>   table, and the related tables represent dimensions. Dimensions provide
>   the means for disaggregating reports into smaller parts. **A row in a
>   fact table usually contains either the value of a measure or a foreign
>   key reference to a dimension table. The row represents the current
>   state of every item covered by the fact table.** For example, the Work
>   Item fact table has one row for every work item stored in Work Item
>   operational store.
>
> A dimension table stores the set of values that exist for a given
>   dimension. Dimensions may be shared between different fact tables and
>   cubes, and they may be referenced by a single fact table or data cube.
>   A Person dimension, for example, will be referenced by the Work Items
>   fact table for Assigned To, Opened By, Resolved By, and Closed By
>   properties, and it will be referenced by the Code Churn fact table for
>   the Checked In By property.
>
> Measures are values taken from the operational data. For example,
>   Total Churn is a measure that indicates the number of source code
>   changes in the selected changesets. Count is a special measure in that
>   it can be implicit, as long as there is one record for every item that
>   is counted. The measures defined in a fact table form a measure group
>   in the cube.
>
> For more information about the **facts, dimensions, and measures** in the
>   data warehouse, see [Perspectives and measure groups provided in the
>   Analysis Services cube.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/perspective-measure-groups-cube)

Refer to [Components of the TFS data warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/components-data-warehouse) for details.